# Group values and check if the values ​from another column cancel each other out in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I need to check if the value inside "CP" columns of a dataframe, while my dataframe is grouped by "Centre" column, are canceling each others.

Here is an example :
Sample :

| Centre | CP |
| --- | --- |
| 3N7D | 10 |
| 3N1F | 2 |
| 3N90 | -9 |
| 3N7D | -1 |
| 3N7D | -10 |
| 8D92 | 198 |
| 3N7D | -10 |
| 3N90 | 2 |
| 8D92 | -195 |
| 8D92 | -3 |

result excepted :

| Centre | CP | Cancel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3N7D | 10 | Canceled |
| 3N1F | 2 |  |
| 3N90 | -9 |  |
| 3N7D | -1 |  |
| 3N7D | -10 | Canceled |
| 8D92 | 198 | (not canceled with -195 and -3 because I need to cancel it only if there is 1 value that cancel, like -198 in one time) |
| 3N7D | -10 | (not canceled because the only 10 is already canceled) |
| 3N90 | 2 |  |
| 8D92 | -195 |  |
| 8D92 | -3 |  |

Here is what I tried :

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("Centre")
for name, group in grouped_df:
    cp_values = group["CP"].values
    for i in range(len(cp_values)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(cp_values)):
            if cp_values[i] == -cp_values[j]:
                print("i = ",i)
                print("j = ",j)
                print("CP = ",cp_values[i])
                print("CP2 = ",cp_values[j])
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to identify the matches of a number with its negative counterpart (obtained with [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html). You will need to deduplicate the values using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) for the `pivot`:

```
tmp = (
 df.assign(sign=np.sign(df['CP']),
           n=df.groupby(['Centre', 'CP']).cumcount(),
           abs=df['CP'].abs()
          ).reset_index()
   .pivot(index=['Centre', 'abs', 'n'], columns='sign', values='index')
)

keep = tmp.where(tmp.notna().all(axis=1)).stack().values

df.loc[keep, 'Cancel'] = 'Canceled'
```

Output:

```
  Centre   CP    Cancel
0   3N7D   10  Canceled
1   3N1F    2       NaN
2   3N90   -9       NaN
3   3N7D   -1       NaN
4   3N7D  -10  Canceled
5   8D92  198       NaN
6   3N7D  -10       NaN
7   3N90    2       NaN
8   8D92 -195       NaN
9   8D92   -3       NaN
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
sign           -1    1
Centre abs n          
3N1F   2   0  NaN  1.0
3N7D   1   0  3.0  NaN
       10  0  4.0  0.0  # indices 0 and 4 cancel each other
           1  6.0  NaN  # indice 6 is alone
3N90   2   0  NaN  7.0
       9   0  2.0  NaN
8D92   3   0  9.0  NaN
       195 0  8.0  NaN
       198 0  NaN  5.0
```